# Primefaces columToggler losing effect on filters

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a lazy datatable with filters, also have the option of toggling columns with the , it works fine on the first time, but if i remove let's say 3 columns and then make a new filter the columToggler keep's its state of selection and the headers of those columns are invisible as well, but the values come up again...
Sounds a little weird explaining, so i'll illustrate it.

[image: Original]

So after the columns are selected i get:

[image: Filtered]

But when i do some filtering or ordering on the dataTable i get:
[image: messedup]

I'm declaring my columnToggler the following way:

```
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Lista de CSRs

                    <p:commandButton id="toggler" update="@form" type="button"
                        value="Columns" style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
                    <p:columnToggler datasource="csrTable" trigger="toggler" />
                </f:facet>
```

If any other information that is needed was omitted please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer on the primefaces blog: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3341

I changed my columToggler to:

```
<p:columnToggler datasource="csrTable" trigger="toggler" >
                        <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{csrBean.onToggle}" />
                    </p:columnToggler>
```

And on my Bean i added the following:

```
private List<Boolean> colunas; //Getters and setters

public void init(){

       setColunas(Arrays.asList(true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true));
}

public void onToggle(ToggleEvent e) {
        getColunas().set((Integer) e.getData(), e.getVisibility() == Visibility.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Then i just added the rendered state on each colum:

```
<p:column headerText="Numero" sortBy="#{csr.numero}"
                    filterBy="#{csr.numero}" rendered="#{csrBean.colunas[0]}">
```

And done.